# Emergency Mode: Network interface

Tags: centos, networking, filesystems, network-interface

A colleague changed the network interface on a production server using 'nmtui' trying to set up a bridged adapter so that the VM set up could be assigned it's own IP.  So he edited a new connection then in ethernet add new connection he put in enp0.  Server boots into emergency mode now.  I don't see any errors when I "journalctl -xe"

I see `systemctl`shows red font with sys.logsocket loaded failed failed syslog Socket.

```
nmcli c show "Error: Could not create NMClient object: Could not connect: No such file or directory.

nmcli d "Error: Could not create NMClient object: Could not connect: No such file or directory.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run `systemctl` without any parameters to see which services have failed? For NetworkManager, run `nmcli c show` to see the connections and their states, then e.g. `nmcli c show enp0` to see more information about a connection named `enp0`. Also `nmcli d show` will display what NetworkManager knows about the actual network interface devices.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I added responses to your questions in the question. Could not connect. This is because the colleague messed up the network interface.

Comment: No, this is because you're in emergency mode. NetworkManager is not running in emergency mode, and neither is dbus-daemon.

Comment: Check that all the filesystems listed in `/etc/fstab` have either been successfully mounted or have a `nofail` or `noauto` mount option. Without either of those options, if a local filesystem cannot be mounted, you'll land into emergency mode for sure.

Comment: Is this CentOS 7 or 8? It looks like in RHEL/CentOS 7, the syslog socket might fail uncleanly when the system transitions into emergency mode, while in RHEL/CentOS 8 the `syslog.socket` has a specific `Conflicts=emergency.target` line. So the syslog failure might be an effect, not a cause. Also, because of parallel operations, the error might not be at the end of `journalctl -xe` output - have you scrolled it back all the way to the beginning? (the `-e` option opens the log to display the tail end first)